# What should I call a person sharing knowledge in school that is not a teacher?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, usage, word-difference, formal-language

Some time ago I was asked by a school institution to conduct a lesson for children about filmmaking. I'm not a teacher, I never attended any pedagogical university and I don't have qualifications to teach in school.

I was invited as a guest to talk about my profession (filmmaking) and to inspire children to create movies, teaching them a little bit about software, copyrights and equipment. Of course, during that lesson the real teacher was present as well, but I was the one giving a speech.

**Question: What was my role?** Was I a tutor? A teacher? A trainer?

I want to include this as a volunteer job in my resume, but I don't know how should I call it. The best I came up with is *Education Volunteer*, but I'm not sure it's good in that context.

Comment: Small tip: you should say "at school", not "in school". When you're "at school", you're talking within the context of the educational system. "In school" suggests "inside the school building". Someone sharing knowledge "at school" would be doing so regardless of where they are physically located.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In AmE, you weren't a tutor, a teacher, or a trainer. Broadly speaking, a tutor's primary job is to help with homework; the teacher was the "real teacher" that was there; a trainer usually helps with physical training (but not always). The term that I could think of was  *guest speaker*. From M-W

> [guest speaker](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guest%20speaker)
>   a person invited to a gathering to give a speech <*He was the guest speaker at the awards ceremony.*>

Comment: Guest lecturer might also work depending on the situation. In the OPs case I'd go with "guest speaker." Guest lecturer is commonly used in university settings where the lesson resembles something a lecturer or professor might give. This type of talk is often about research topic the guest speaker specializes in.